# livy curl request error for Kerberos Cloudera Hadoop

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, cloudera, livy

Configured livy server on kerberized CDH 5.10.x and its running fine on port 8998, but curl request giving below error,

**curl --negotiate -u : http://xxxxxxx:8998/sessions**

> Error 403
>
> ### HTTP ERROR: 403
>
> Problem accessing
>   /sessions. Reason:
>
> ```
>     GSSException: No valid credentials
> provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos
> credentails)
> ```
>
> ---
>
> *Powered by Jetty://*

unable to get why request is not going through kerberos security layer?

Answer (score 2):

This error indicates that your kerberos ticket most likely doesn't exist or expired.

Have you run `kinit` to create your kerberos ticket?

Comment: Yeah Tagar, I did kinit again and created ticket but still it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

For Testing purpose, Can you kinit as `hdfs` user using (you can find the keytab under HDFS roles machine - Namenode, Datanode /var/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process/*hdfs*/hdfs.keytab)

`kinit -kt hdfs.keytab hdfs/hostname@REALM`

or kinit as your user `kinit user@REALM`

And then try

`curl --negotiate -u :  -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://xxxx.xxxx:8998/sessions`

In order to find pyspark sessions,

`curl --negotiate -u :  -X POST --data '{"kind": "pyspark"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://xxxxx:8998/sessions`

Comment: Currently I am running with system user, I tried above command but it doesn't worked, It's giving error as, "kinit: Generic preauthentication failure while getting initial credentials".

Comment: What’s the name of the system user?

Comment: It's something like sys<any-name>. This user able to access hadoop services without security issue.

Comment: can you knit as  sys<any-name> and try again

Comment: -1 as normal users shouldn't use (or shouldn't even have access to) service accounts' keytabs.. and hdfs/_HOST is a service account that used by the HDFS services themselves. hdfs user is a "superuser" that bypasses normal security imposed on other users. so again it's a bad idea to suggest that.

Comment: I agree! I should've added the hdfs kinit for testing purpose. Again, he's using system user(trying to understand what it is)